# Laravel/Mysql- Access denied for 'user'@localhost

Tags: mysql, laravel, permissions

Im having an issue with mysql after reinstalling wamp on my computer for a laravel project. When i try to run php artisan migrate i get

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'scompean'@'localhost' 
(using  password: YES)
```

Im pretty positive my .env file is correct:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=compean
DB_USERNAME=scompean
DB_PASSWORD=tmp1234,
```

The user scompean exists and db compean exists, i have checked this in phpmyadmin and i can login using this user who has global privileges so im not sure how this says access denied? it seems i cant access mysql through command line either

when i run mysql -u scompean -p

I would expect a enter password:

but i dont get anything i just see a cursor(|) sitting there in terminal 
so im not sure whats going on. I have researched and have even tried

```
php artisan config:clear
```

but that didnt work either. Im not an expert in mysql so im not really sure what else to try from here? Perhaps an old config file from the previous wamp that was installed is causing the issue? Not sure (>:/)

Comment: i doubt it makes a difference but i use gitbash for my terminal.

Comment: Did you entered your passworD?

Comment: You can login from your terminal `$ mysql -u scompean -ptmp1234,` ?

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar yeah i tried that too
Just get mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. and the blinking cursor :/

Answer (score 1):

Change the file content of `phpmyadmin.conf` and do like so :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restart your Apache server after making these changes.

Comment: I ended up just uninstalling wamp and reinstalling it and it worked, but i will keep this solution in mind for future problems lol. Thanks though:)